# Popup notification on table change?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery, logic

I have a table for users Badges and Achievements. The default value for a Badge is written as **locked** in the field value for each badge.  Then when the user unlocks the badge the field value is updated to **unlocked**. How could I alert the user with a popup message that alerts them that they have just unlocked a new achievement based on the value change?

Comment: Please clarify what does it mean? "How could I alert the user with a popup message that alerts them that they have just unlocked a new achievement"

Comment: Exactly what it says.  How can I have a notification or a popup message display on screen if the field value in my sql table changes to "unlocked" letting them know they just received a new badge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have to do with Javascript, and the onclick(alert('unlocked')) or something along those lines.

Comment: Among those  line? Which lines?

Comment: adding the achievements in a array, and testing the array in the if statement, with the function in the if statement being echo '<script>alert('you unlocked achievement')</script>';
thats telling php, that whenever the array gets tested true, then print that code out in html, and html will read the alret as javascript and js will tell it to alert user.

Comment: only problem is, won't that alert them every time or just once?

Comment: it would,  h/o im going to write a quick code, cause i wanna help you, it would be easier then writing in words lol. 

How exactly do you unlock the achievements? like the exact action, is there a game written in javascript wehre if u do a function it unlocks?

Comment: @ELHippie <?php
if($Points >= "10000") {
    $awardBadge = mysql_query("UPDATE login_users SET maneki='unlocked' WHERE username='$username'");
} else {
    print "image if user hasn't unlocked the badge";
 
}
?>

Comment: @ELHippie in a table the default value of the badge fields are "locked" and then become "unlocked" through the above script :)

Comment: @AoiHana what exactly do you do to get the points? and do the points ever reset? you have to save the if statement as a function like
function unlockingpoints() {
if($Points >= "10000") { $awardBadge = mysql_query("UPDATE login_users SET maneki='unlocked' WHERE username='$username'"); } 

then you gotta check the database for anything with unlocked values, and then do another if statement saying that alert('unlocked!') in javascript and that same statement return the function unlockingpoints

Comment: @ELHippie That is great :) What could I do though to make sure the alert only shows once? Thanks for your great help on this!

Comment: @AoiHana no problem :D, and you'd have to have something to remember the points the user has, or if it resets, like a pacman game, you have to have something the checks if the maneki value is unlocked or locked, if unlocked alert('congratulations!') and in that same if statement, return that unlockingpoints function, to actually change the database value in mysql, and this if statement will only happen if maneki value equals unlocked, it wont happen again cause you will have changed the value to locked and its only looking for unlocked, but it really depends on how you get the points.